# Docker: How to create a table for local dynamo DB?

Tags: docker, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to create a docker container with local Amazon Dynamo DB. And it actually works. But I can not understand how to create a table for this image in Docker file?

Through the javascript I create a table like this:

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'UserActivity',
    KeySchema: [ 
        {
            AttributeName: 'user_id',
            KeyType: 'HASH',
        },
        {
            AttributeName: 'user_action', 
            KeyType: 'RANGE', 
        }
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [
        {
            AttributeName: 'user_id',
            AttributeType: 'S',
        },
        {
            AttributeName: 'user_action',
            AttributeType: 'S',
        }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {
        ReadCapacityUnits: 2, 
        WriteCapacityUnits: 2, 
    }
};
dynamodb.createTable(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) ppJson(err); // an error occurred
    else ppJson(data); // successful response

});
```

And here is my Docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

ENV DYNAMODB_VERSION=latest

RUN apk add --update curl && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && \
    curl -O https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-local/dynamodb_local_${DYNAMODB_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
    tar zxvf dynamodb_local_${DYNAMODB_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
    rm dynamodb_local_${DYNAMODB_VERSION}.tar.gz

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.library.path=.", "-jar", "DynamoDBLocal.jar",  "--sharedDb", "-inMemory", "-port", "8000"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was in base image which I used for local dynamodb. I mean *openjdk:8-jre-alpine*
Looks like the alpine distribution does not have something important for functioning of local dynamodb.
So here is a working Dockerfile for local dynamodb:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre

ENV DYNAMODB_VERSION=latest

COPY .aws/ root/.aws/

RUN curl -O https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-local/dynamodb_local_${DYNAMODB_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
    tar zxvf dynamodb_local_${DYNAMODB_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
    rm dynamodb_local_${DYNAMODB_VERSION}.tar.gz

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.library.path=.", "-jar", "DynamoDBLocal.jar",  "--sharedDb", "-inMemory"]
```

I'd be happy to read what is the main problem of **alpine** in this particular case.

Answer (score 11):

You need to point your DynamoDB client to the local DynamoDB endpoint.

Do something like:

```
dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({
    endpoint: new AWS.Endpoint('http://localhost:8000')
});
dynamodb.createTable(...);
```

**UPDATE**

Alternatively you can use AWS CLI to create tables in your local DynamoDB without using JavaSciprt code. You need to use the "--endpoint-url" to point CLI to your local instance like this:

```
aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

You need to use [create-table](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/create-table.html) command to create a table.

Comment: Ivan thanks. But looks like this method is inappropriate for implementation of table creation within the Dockerfile

Comment: I don't think I understand you. What do you mean by "inappropriate"? DynamoDB local should provide the same interface as a regular DynamoDB.

Comment: Exactly. But I need to create a Docker file which will contain operation of a table creation, so it's not a case for me to create a Docker container and just after that connect to it and create a table

Comment: Ok, got it. You can use AWS CLI for that and specify local endpoint

Comment: After I run the `docker exec -it vidiq-dynamodb aws dynamodb create-table --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000 --table-name UserActivity ...bla-bla...` I receive back "You must specify a region. You can also configure your region by running "aws configure""

Comment: I guess this is because you didn't run "aws configure" command in a Docker container. Could you run "aws configure" first?

Comment: If you are trying to make it work in Docker container, try to run local dynamo outside Docker container and make sure that your commands work, then add extra complexity. Here is how to run local DynamoDB: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html

Comment: I tried to rub locally without docker through the localhost/shell. A table was created successfully. But through the cli doesn't work, despite the cli configuration is completed well